# Swashbuckle dynamically change header value

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I can set the header in swashbuckle however on each send request I need to change header value, the reason I need to do is because we have authentication code(basically it is library) which generates a token for each api request so in order to generate token it takes url, body and so on... 
So I 'm looking a way where in on each api request our internal code which generates token is called sets the value against the header and pass to actual controller which will again generate a token in order to compare with the header token.

```
void IOperationFilter.Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
            {
                if (operation.Parameters == null)
                    operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
                operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "Content",
                    In = "header",
                    Description = "Content",
                    Required = true,
                    Type = "string"
                });
                operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "AuthorizationToken",
                    In = "header",
                    Description = "Token",
                    Required = false,
                    Type = "string"
                });
            }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the swagger setting EnableApiKeySupport()

Comment: @MXD I don't see any specific settings could you please help